# string.find(), e se eu quiser criar algo parecido?

Tags: c#, c++

Galera, eu gostaria de saber como funciona essas "coisas" na qual não sei o nome, no caso string.find(), string.copy(), string.erase(); Tudo oque eu sei fazer é stringpick(string).
Lembrando que apenas citei exemplos, oque eu queria mesmo é saber como se chama aqueles coisas ali pra eu poder dar uma estudada :D

Comment: Tente clarificar melhor sua pergunta, se não sabe o nome pelo menos explique o que deseja. A pergunta fala de coisas que ninguém tem ideia do que seja.

Comment: Essas coisas se chamam métodos.

Answer (score 1):

Ícaro,

Pelo que entendi você já sabe utilizar funções, porém ainda não tem o conhecimento de orientação a objetos.

O string.find() por exemplo que você citou seria a chamada de uma função pertencente a uma classe ou a um objeto (se for em C++ seria um objeto, se fosse em C# poderiam ser qualquer um dos dois, pois a sintaxe é diferente).

Estas funções pertencentes a classes são conhecidas em Orientação a Objetos como métodos.

Procure estudar o conceito de Orientação a Objetos e colocá-lo em prática com alguma linguagem de programação para fundamentar seus estudos com a parte prática também.

Comment: Ok! Um conhecido meu me disse pra eu procurar sobre descendência, e eu acabei encontrando a resposta